# I am unable to open weekviewcontroller using sscalendar

Tags: ios, swift, events, calendar

I am using SSCalendar third lib for developing week view events in my app. and I am unable to open week-view-controller in that. help me. thanks

```
" let weekViewController = SSCalendarWeekViewController(view: Collection)"
```

**showing error:** Cannot convert value of type 'Collection.Protocol' to expected argument type 'UICollectionView!'

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: show your tried code in question!

Comment: @iPatel  problem is set up sscalendarviewcontroller     "  let weekViewController = SSCalendarWeekViewController(view: Collection)" .   showing error:  Cannot convert value of type 'Collection.Protocol' to expected argument type 'UICollectionView!'

Comment: @Lion please check my update question .